# Constructor overloading resolution and compilation

Tags: c++11, constructor

Having a structure TB with 3 constructors, the code below compiles and the copy constructor - "Constructor A" is called twice. Commenting out "constructor C" causes compilation problem.

What is the reason for that?

Why uncommenting the const in constructor B influences the compilation result?

Is this related to overriding the default copy assignment operator?

What are the resolution rules which apply here?

```
int doIgetHere = 0;

struct TA{
    int a;
};

struct TB{
    int b;
    //Constructor A
    TB(TA &ta){
        b = ta.a;
    }

    //Constructor B 
    TB(/*const*/ TB &tb){
        doIgetHere++;
        b = tb.b;
    }

    // Constructor C === removing this constructor cause compilation problem, why ?
    TB(TB && mtb){
        doIgetHere++;
        b = mtb.b;
    }
};

int main(){
    TA ta;     

    TB tb1(ta);  // using constructor A
    TB tb2 = ta; // using constructor A     

    std::cout<<doIgetHere<<"\n"; // result is 0, as expected
}
```

Compilation log:

> 34:5: error: no viable constructor copying variable of type 'TB'
>
> ```
>     TB tb2 = ta; // using constructor A  
>
>        ^     ~~
> ```
>
> 18:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
>
> ```
>     TB(/*const*/ TB &tb){  
>
>     ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

Comment: When asking about "compilation problems" please *include* the "problems". Please edit your question to include the errors, copy-pasted (as text), complete, in full, including any possible informational notes and without modifications.

Comment: Regarding your constructors, [copy-constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) (your "Constructor B") should have their argument be a `const` reference. And [move-constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) (your "Constructor C") should have its argument be a non-const rvalue reference.

Comment: Please [***edit your question***](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45979754/edit) to include the errors or other crucial and relevant information. And don't forget to copy-paste the *complete* output.

Comment: I expected that as only "Constructor A" is used, adding arbitrary constructors would not cause compilation problems, unless it is somehow related to overriding default constructors, am I wrong?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I fixed the move constructor, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
TB tb2 = ta;
```

it is actually equal to

```
TB tb2 = TB(ta);
```

In other words, a *temporary* object is created from `ta` which is then used in the *copy-constructor* (your constructor B).

The problem here is that non-const references can not bind to temporary objects. The solution is simply to make the argument a constant reference (which you commented out for some reason).

With your non-standard move-constructor (your constructor C) you *can* take temporary objects as arguments, that part of how rvalue references works.

Comment: I do not understand why only constructor A is used although Constructor B and Constructor C are available.  The variable doIgetHere keeps being zero when the three constructors are there.

Comment: @Nir You should probably read about a compiler-optimization called [*copy elision*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Even though the copy-constructor might not be called, it still have to exist (properly declared). In this case I would suggest you default it, like e.g. `TB(TB const&) = default;`